# Add values of similar json

Tags: json, clojure

I am having the 2 exactly similar JSON object, I want to add the values of corresponding keys and return a single JSON. The JSON will contain JSON array also. What is the idiomatic way of doing in clojure ?

**Input JSON 1:**

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "val1":{
            "total":"1.00",
            "val2":{
               "total":"1.00"
            },
            "val3":{
               "total":"1.00"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

**Input JSON 2:**

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "val1":{
            "total":"2.00",
            "val2":{
               "total":"3.00"
            },
            "val3":{
               "total":"4.00"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

**Expected JSON :**

```
{
       "data":[
          {
             "val1":{
                "total":"3.00",
                "val2":{
                   "total":"4.00"
                },
                "val3":{
                   "total":"5.00"
                }
             }
          }
       ]
    }
```

Comment: imho your json is not correct. it has  duplicate key 'val2'

Comment: @minhtuannguyen sorry, its just typo.

Comment: please post the code you have wrote to solve the problem

Comment: @mavbozo We are new to clojure so we are looking for lib or idiomatic way in clojure.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to parse the json.

Add `[org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]` to your `:dependencies` vector.

```
(ns foo.bar
  (:require
   [clojure.data.json :as json]))

(defn read-input [path]
  ;; Substitute slurp for however you get the input.
  (json/read-str (slurp path)
                 :key-fn keyword ; In clojure it's nice to have keys as keywords
                 :value-fn (fn [k v]
                             ;; Parse the numbers.
                             (if (= :total k)
                               (Double/parseDouble v)
                               v))))

(def input1 (read-input "input1.json"))
(def input2 (read-input "input2.json"))


;; The parsed input.
(def input1 {:data [{:val1 {:total 5.0, :val2 {:total 4.0}, :val3 {:total 3.0}}}]})
(def input2 {:data [{:val1 {:total 1.0, :val2 {:total 1.0}, :val3 {:total 1.0}}}]})
```

Then to merge them you can use the nice core function `merge-with` and some recursion.

```
(defn merge-jsons [a b]
  (merge-with (fn [v1 v2]
                (cond (every? vector? [v1 v2]) (mapv merge-jsons v1 v2)
                      (every? map? [v1 v2]) (merge-jsons v1 v2)
                      :else (+ v1 v2)))
              a, b))
```

Then you just need to transform it back to json.

(`write-str` has a `:value-fn` option just like `read-str` if you really need the numbers here to be strings)

```
(json/write-str (merge-jsons input1 input2))
;;=> "{\"data\":[{\"val1\":{\"total\":3.0,\"val2\":{\"total\":4.0},\"val3\":{\"total\":5.0}}}]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by 3 steps. I have mentioned them in the code below as comments.

## Clojure string is too powerful.

```
(def input1 {:val1 {:total 5, :val2 {:total 4}, :val3 {:total 3}}})                                                                                                                                         
(def input2 {:val1 {:total 1, :val2 {:total 1}, :val3 {:total 1}}})                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
;; Step 1: Flatten the data                                                                                                                                                                                 
(defn flatten-input [input]                                                                                                                                                                                 
  (let [values (str "[" (clojure.string/replace (str input) #"([{]*[:]*[a-zA-Z]+[1-9]*)|([}])|([,])" "") "]")]                                                                                              
       (read-string values)))                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
;; Step 2: Sum the data                                                                                                                                                                                     
(defn sum-the-data [& inputs]                                                                                                                                                                               
  (apply map +  inputs))                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
;; Step 3: Convert it into the  original data structure                                                                                                                                                     
(defn get-final-data [summed-data]
  (let [string-data (apply format "{:val1 {:total %s, :val2 {:total %s}, :val3 {:total %s}}}" summed-data)]                                                                                                 
        (read-string string-data)))                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
(defn main []
   (let [flattened-input1 (flatten-input input1)                                                                                                                                                             
         flattened-input2 (flatten-input input2)                                                                                                                                                             
         summed-data (sum-the-data flattened-input1 flattened-input2)]                                                                                                                                       
   (prn (get-final-data summed-data))))
```

Disclaimer: This will only work with data structures with no vectors.

Note: Please comment for anything which might be more time consuming than the traditional approach.